# Postgresql user can login without password or with wrong password in same machine even if I switch from trust to md5 in pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql

Hi I am new in postgresql.But I have background of sql server.I try to understand security concept of postgres.I use windows 10 and I want to restrict postgres user's login without password.I searched for this and as far as i understand this can be achieved in pg_hba.config.I changed from

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

to

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

and restarted postgresql service.But still postgresql user can login without password or with wrong password.Password validation does not seem to work.

When I try to login from another machine.Password validation works.
Because

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

in pg_hba.config works.

Why Does not it work in localhost for postgres user? How can i achieve this ?

pg_hba.config's content

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD
# IPv4 local & remote connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

By the way I am using postgresql 11 version.

Comment: Could you post the all relevant lines from pg_hba file? Meaning without comments.

Comment: I added pg_hba.config's content in post

Comment: If I understand your post correctly problem is actually with logins from the same machine? You say - "When I try to login from another machine.Password validation works." Are you sure there is no line like "local   all             all                                     trust" in your pg_hba? If not could you try to add "local   all             all                                     md5" reload configuration ("select pg_reload_conf()" in psql is sufficient) and test it?

Comment: I got psql: FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf after added local all all md5.Can you post working sample pg_hba.conf ?

Comment: OK there must be some wrong formatting in your file. Check documentation - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/auth-pg-hba-conf.html - Example 20-1 - at the bottom of the page

Comment: Your configuration file looks correct. Maybr you got the wrong file or some other trivial mistake.

Comment: I tried it like documentation but when i run psql,postgresql service stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved this problem.As I say,I use windows 10.When I searched for this problem deeply,I found [Postgresql user can login without password or with wrong password in same machine even if I switch from trust to md5 in pg_hba.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55529784/postgresql-user-can-login-without-password-or-with-wrong-password-in-same-machin) post.This post contains a comment that is
"Looks like I had a password set over here which was causing problems, C:\Users*****\AppData\Roaming/postgresql/pgpass.conf All sorted now, thanks!".
When I look pgpass.conf in this directory and empty this file,it works as I want.
As a result,If we make md5 authentication and want to force password in command promt,we have to empty this file.As postgresql document says in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-pgpass.html
if a connection requires password like in md5 authentication,this pgpass.conf is used implicitly.So If we want more security,we must realize this file and empty it.